# How to do a group by on a concatenated Field?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

Say I have  a table for students attending school like this:

```
St_ID |St_Name|Class_ID|Year
------+-------+--------+----
 02345|John   |     345|2011
 07871|Jane   |     234|2010
```

and so on.
I wish to run queries on each Class which I can get by concatenating Class_ID & Year.
i.e 345-2011 is one class

How do I do count(*), by having the concatenated string in the Group by query?

Comment: I know that the database is not normalized, but these people have been keeping their data in excel for a long time, and have just started with databases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two options:

1) Add the concatenated column to the group by clause

Eg.

```
SELECT columna || columnb || columnc
FROM table
GROUP BY columna || columnb || columnc
```

2) Add each column that apart's the concatenated column in the group by seperately

Eg.

```
SELECT columna || columnb || columnc
FROM table
GROUP BY columna, columnb, columnc
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to concatenate them, just list all three columns in the `GROUP BY` statement.

If you do have to concatenate then just put the concatenate command in the GROUP BY.

Comment: I know you were first, but niktrs' answer was more detailed, so I have accepted that answer

Comment: "If you do have to concatenate then just put the concatenate command in the GROUP BY." 
That was what i was looking for :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
select Class_ID||Year as class_year, count(*)
from table
group by 1
```

With `group by` you can refer to the column *number*.

Anal-rententives will suggest you should refer to the expression, like this: `group by Class_ID||Year`, but I think it's clearer as the number, because it's easier to read and especially because if you later *change* the expression, you don't have to remember to *also* change the expression in the group by.

Comment: Is this working in Oracle; I am asking this because this is not accepted in SQL server

Comment: It's not. You can't even group by column alias.

Comment: I prefer things to break if not done correctly, there is a greater potential for errors with this type of query, as it will run and return incorrect results , why bother just to short cut typing a few characters ?